# Extension for keeping a global list of files in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a extension that will allow me to bookmark or favorite files **across workspaces**. I've tried extensions like Bookmarks and Favorites, but the problem is they only scope these files to the workspace you're in and not globally.

Comment: I have the same problem, this is as close as i've seen it. https://github.com/kdcro101/vscode-favorites/issues/32 for this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kdcro101.favorites